# Array from text and showed in tableView

Tags: arrays, swift, swift2

I am creating an application that, written a string in a textfield, saves it in an array. The array is showed in a tableViewController embedded in the mainViewController. The situation is the following.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/z5uTc.png.
I want that every time I tap the green "Save" button, the string I wrote in the textField is saved and showed in the tableView and the textField returns empty, so I can re-write a string, that is added in the array. The tableView, in this case, shows the two strings, I wrote in the same textField. I tried to write the code for the two viewControllers (the mainViewVC and the tableVC).

MainVC

```
import UIKit

class mainVC: UIViewController {
@IBOutlet var txtField: UITextField!
var embTableVC: tableVC!

override func viewDidLoad() {
 super.viewDidLoad()
 // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
 super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
 // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
 if segue.identifier == "embededTableVC" {
    embTableVC = segue.destinationViewController as! tableVC
 }
}

@IBAction func Save() {
 if let Text = txtField.text {
     if txtField.text == "" {
        myArray.append(Text)
        let row = myArray.count-1
        let indexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: row, inSection: 0)
        embTableVC.myTableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
    }
}
 txtField.text = ""
 txtField.resignFirstResponder()
}     
}
```

TableVC

```
  import UIKit

  var myArray = [String]()

  class tableVC: UITableViewController {
  @IBOutlet var myTableView: UITableView! {
didSet {
    myTableView.dataSource = self
    myTableView.delegate = self
}
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
 super.viewDidLoad()
 myTableView.dataSource = self
 myTableView.delegate = self
 myTableView.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier:   "customcell")
 // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

}

override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
 super.viewDidAppear(animated)
 myTableView.reloadData()
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
 super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
 // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
 }

 override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
 return 1
  }


override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
return myArray.count
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
let cell = myTableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("customcell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell

cell.textLabel?.text = myArray[indexPath.item]

return cell
}
```

The code I wrote doesn't work. I can compile and run the application on my device, but when I tap the green "Save" button, the app crashes. The error message is "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an optional value" on the line:    `embTableVC.myTableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Fade)` in the "Save" IBAction.
Can you help me?
Thanks a lot:)

Answer (score 0):

You init embTableVC only when you segue to the next ViewController, but you try to access it at your save function, while it is still nil.

init it before you access it.

Comment: Before the class you mean?

Comment: You try to update something that is not yet exists.
instead of var embTableVC: tableVC! , write something like var embTableVC = embTableVC()  
(but maybe it would be better if you move the "save function" to the embTableVC class